# how to set a location by latitude longitude in gmap3

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript and trying to use the gmap3 script. I want to show a specific place in my map through atitude and longitude I tried with the after have created 2 variables for both lat and lng.

```
var lat = $("#localizacao_lat").text();
var lng = $("#localizacao_lng").text();

   $(function() {
        $("#map").gmap3({
marker:{
        latLng: [lat, lng],
```

but I couldn't show anything in my map.If someone could help me with this issue where my problem is I would be more than pleased. Please find the code below the complete  source code.

Thanks.
Jimmy

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

         $(function() {
        $("#map").gmap3({
          map:{
            options:{
              zoom: 14,
            }
          },
          getlatlng:{ 

        /*    address:  " ,*/    //Type the address 

            callback: function(results) {
              if ( !results ) return;
              $(this).gmap3('get').setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()));
              $(this).gmap3({
                marker:{
                  latLng:results[0].geometry.location,
                  options:{
                      icon:    'images/map-pin.png'
                    }
                }
              });
            }  
          }

        });

        });
    </script>
```

P.S I want to show through lng and lat not by address. !